# Hide particular div if all elements have the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of same elements on the page. All those elements have this particular structure:

```html
<div id="9p" class="col s12 m6 l2 cardmaion globalcardclass">
    <div class="card 9p">
        <div class="card-content ">
            <div class="row card-row">
                <!-- a bunch of divs -->

                <!-- a line of a card -->
                <a data-category="here" class="hidden">
                    <div style="border-top:2px dotted gray;font-size:18px;background:ivory;margin-top:1px;"
                        id="belanimation" class="card-line waves-effect waves-green">
                        Some random text goes here <span class="card-line-q">&nbsp; x 1</span><span
                            class="modspan  "></span></div>
                </a>
                <!-- a line of a card -->
                <a data-category="here" class="hidden">
                    <div style="border-top:2px dotted gray;font-size:18px;background:ivory;margin-top:1px;"
                        id="belanimation" class="card-line waves-effect waves-green">
                        Some random text goes here <span class="card-line-q">&nbsp; x 2</span><span
                            class="modspan  "></span></div>
                </a>
                <!-- a line of a card -->
                <a data-category="here" class="hidden">
                    <div style="border-top:2px dotted gray;font-size:18px;background:ivory;margin-top:1px;"
                        id="belanimation" class="card-line waves-effect waves-green">
                        Some random text goes here <span class="card-line-q">&nbsp; x 2</span><span
                            class="modspan  "></span></div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All the `cards` (example above) have common class = **globalcardclass** (it's only way to track that 'card elements')

All lines in a card could be **(or not!)** contains class = **hidden**

So I want a script to hide the whole card if **all** `<a>` elements (`lines`) have the class = **hidden**

If one or two  elements (`lines`) do not have class **hidden** -- the card is shown.

I need to add another `hide` class to a particular `card` if all its children elements have  class **hidden**.

Here I try something but It doesn't work at all. The hard part is... when the `card` element gets  elements (`lines`) with class **hidden** that card must show up again...

Please, help.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function FilterHere() {
            var emptyCounter = 0
            jQuery(".globalcardclass a").each(function () {
                if ($(this).is('.hidden')) {
                    emptyCounter++
                }
                emptyCounter--
            });
            if (emptyCounter === 0) {
                $(".globalcardclass").hide();
            }
        }
        setTimeout(FilterHere, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

**UPD!**

Here is new way to solve my problem:

[jsfiddle.net/q6cekb18](http://jsfiddle.net/q6cekb18/)

But it also doesn't work...

**UPD 2 (!)**

Finally! I've got some progress!

```
   $(".globalcardclass").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find(".smoothmaion:visible").length == 0;
}).hide();
```

That code is working... All the card are hiding... But...

A card (.globalcardclass) is not showing up if 'line' element (.smoothmaion) becomes visible again... How to make it some sort of a... toggle?

**Yeah... I can:**

```
<script>
  function Filtering()
  {
    $(".globalcardclass").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find(".smoothmaion:visible").length == 0;
}).toggleClass( "hide_hide" )



     };
</script>
```

But... When I use another button to filter different type of elements... That 'toggle' thing brings back that hidden element 'cause it has not change so ... toggle..

What can I do?

Comment: First of all, `emptyCounter` is not the same as `empty` and is also not the same as `emptyConuter`. Fix the spelling errors on your variables.

Comment: Thank you. I did. But it is not the case...

Comment: "So I want a script to hide the whole card" witch one?, all or particular?

Comment: There are plenty of them. All of them.